# Alias for Kate editor

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

How can I create an alias in .bashrc for Kate editor, in order not to write `kate file1 file2`, but `k file1 file2` for opening those files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add  `alias k='kate'`. Here is [a link](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#alias) to some more information on bash aliases.

You can't pass a parameter into an alias. You can do the cd dir_name"=>"cd dir_name; ls -l with a function and an alias like so

```
mcd () { cd "$1" && ls -l; }
alias cd='mcd'
```

That will only execute the `ls -l` if the `cd` is successful.

Comment: ok and how I can alias "cd dir_name"=>"cd dir_name; ls -l"

Answer (score 2):

Alias is not safe and flexible. I always use the function.

```
$c() { cat $*; }
$b() { cd "$1" && ls -l; }
$ b /tmp
total 0
```

Comment: I have not seen it marked depreciated anywhere, although http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html does suggest shell functions over them

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29#Alternatives

Comment: man bash "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions"

Comment: The key words are "almost" and "superseded" (the latter is not a synonym for "deprecated").

Comment: This is recommendation. I don't recommend use let, alias, select in bash. A change 'deprecated' to 'not safe and flexible'.